# Identification of Unknown Insects found in landfill (spider like)

Tags: species-identification, arachnology, arthropod

Could someone help me to identify the following spider-like insects? They are very small, so I used a macro lens to capture them. I have tried to capture them as clearly as possible.

They are about 2-3mm long with a black hairy head/belly.

[image]

They were collected from a closed section of Tseung Kwan O Landfill and Clear Water Bay Country Park of Hong Kong. This area is revegetated so the ecology is much like an area which contains many kind of trees.

Comment: Spiders for sure (4 pairs of legs, two body parts), but very hard to tell from their condition and the quality of the photos.